# Symfony 1.4 doctrine - global database table prefix__%s

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

**I need to set environment specific table prefixes**, so i found unperfect solution in inserting this in ProjectConfiguration::configureDoctrine(Doctrine_Manager $manager):
(config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php)

```
if (sfConfig::get('app_database_table_prefix')) {
    $manager->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_TBLNAME_FORMAT,
    sfConfig::get('app_database_table_prefix'));
}
```

... and then i can set env-unique prefixes in app.yml:

```
prod:
  database_table_prefix: prefix__%s
```

BUT.. this is cool for all app, except plugins.
Plugins ignores config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php.

**Dont you know about alglobal solution WITHOUT changing anything in plugins directory (i need something what will influent all posible future applications plugins too)**

Comment: i found temporary sollution in updating of sfPluginConfiguration::initialize() of concrete plugin by the same code like upper, but substitute $manager by Doctrine_Manager::getInstance(), but its still not final solution which should influent all future plugins without changing anything in their code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using Doctrine, so it looks like you can set the prefix in your `databases.yml` file. The instructions are at the bottom of [this](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/07-Databases) page, but it looks like you can set the table name format by adding the tblname_format to the attributes in databases.yml like so:

```
all:
  doctrine:
    param:
      attributes:
        tblname_format: YOURPREFIX_%s
```